# C++: how to pass 'this' object as pointer reference

Tags: c++

The question is not very clear, because I know that 'this' is const* and I can't modify pointer. I have class Queue and struct Element inside. I have constructor for Element which asign value and pointer to next element. I want to make function Push in Queue class which just create Element object (and pass value to Push function). My Element constructor is

```
Element(Queue*& queue, int value)
```

i must pass Queue object, because in Queue class i have pointer to first and last element of Element structure. So it have to modify my Queue object.
My Push function:

```
    Element* x = new Element(this, x);  [i know that this can't work as i said this is const]
```

main:

```
Queue* q = new Queue();
q.Push(5);
```

How to pass object 'q' as parameter to constructor of Element?

EDIT:
Element constructor:

```
Queue::Element::Element(Queue*& queue, int x)
{
    if (queue->front)
    {
        Element* tmp = queue->front;
        while (tmp->next)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = this;
        this->value = x;
    }
    else
    {
        queue->front = this;
        queue->back = this;
        this->value = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Element` going to do with the pointer? This is important, because if it's going to hold a long lived reference, we cannot create a temporary pointer and assign `this` to it before passing it in (because it would go out of scope afterwards)

Comment: Unless you're wholesale stomping `queue` the reference part is a complete waste of time. **Don't do it**. It just confuses your code and implies you're mutating it, which you're not. You can delete the `&` here without changing how your code works, which means it's completely extraneous.

Comment: It assigns to element which pointer points to values (pointers to Element object). I edited post look code

Comment: Why is your constructor manipulating another object in the first place? That seems...rude. A constructor should focus on preparing the object. Another function should deal with linking it in with other structures. It's a separation of concerns issue here.

Comment: Unrelated: `this` is actually really weird. It's not `const`, well not unless the method itself is `const`, it's what's called a prvalue. [Here's some good reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this).

Comment: You might be mistakenly thinking you need a non-const reference to a pointer in order to do something like `queue->front = ...;`. You don't, that's what regular, undecorated pointers do. Changing `front` requires one level of indirection, not two.

Comment: @tadman it checks if queue is empty. If not it just assign objects of Element struct to Queue pointers

Comment: I know what it does, I'm just saying that is *not* the job of a constructor. This function has assumed too much responsibility. Normally constructors *construct* and another function handles *insertion*.

Comment: I'd go a bit futher than that. `Element` shouldn't know enough about `Queue` to directly interact with `Queue`s internal state (member variables). This couples the two classes far too tightly for my tastes. This is a sign of extremely weak encapsulation, and if you're writing this for a class you may get docked marks. If you're writing this for production, it shouldn't survive a code review. If you're writing this for your own entertainment, do as thou wilt.

Comment: okey, nice to know, i will just make another functions and modify Element constructor. I see know that i can make 'if' statements in push functions so if my first idea was bad i go other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a simple pointer to the Element() constructor:

```
Queue::Element::Element(Queue* queue, int x)
```

The only thing you need to assure, is that `Element` can access `Queue::front` and `Queue::back`. For instance, if they are private members of `Queue`, then you can make `Element` a `friend` of `Queue`, something like:

```
class Queue {
//...
friend class Element;
//...
```

Edit: haven't noticed that you do modify `Queue` inside `Element`.

Comment: I want to modify Queue object pointers. To modify them i can't pass Queue* queue (pointer) because it will make changes in function (local not global)

Comment: Please explain your goals more clearly. See: [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Kawson - once you pass a pointer to Queue into `Element()`, the changes you make on the pointed object will not be function-local, but _will_ modify your Queue object. That's how passing pointers as function parameters works - you cannot modify the _address_ of `this` object passed to a call to `Element()`, but you can modify the memory at that address (so the contents of Queue object).

Comment: @Tomek Oh.. If it does, it solves my problem. I just wanted to modify Queue object variables (not address as you said).

Comment: @tadman the problem was that i want to edit object variables ('this' object) and i thought that i have to reference to "original" object, not copy but it works fine if i pass pointer and dont have to edit address. So there is no problem but i nice to know about XY. Didnt see this before but it is true in my case.
EDIT:
but even if i want to edit 'this' object address (delete or smth else) is it possible to edit this address? or it is violation of the rules c++ or smth?

Comment: That's a very confused description of what's going on, so you may want to pull back and think about what you're doing at a higher level instead of charging ahead on the assumption you need to do things a particular way. You'll often find that when you're going *against concerns* you end up with highly convoluted, very intertwined code, which you can untangle by thinking about it a different way and organizing things better.

Comment: General rule: You **cannot** change `this`. Treat it as effectively immutable. Any solution that requires altering it is one that's going about it the wrong way. It's not just against C++ rules, it's going against a lot of other principles. The reason C++ doesn't allow doing it is because it's usually not the right call.

Comment: @Kawson - It's perfectly legal to `delete` the Queue object. You can do `delete queue;` from within `Element()`, and also you can do `delete this;` from within the `Queue` object itself. That's because when you do that, you are not modifying the _address_ stored inside `this` pointer, but you are freeing memory _at_ that address. What you can't do, is assigning a different address to `this` pointer (so you can't do `this = something_else;`). You still can, however, do `queue = something_else;`, but that would make `queue` point to a totally different object than your original `Queue` instance.